# Вытащить строку в регулярке php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Есть строка `$str = 'text1[text2](text3){text4}';`. Пытаюсь вытащить в этой строке всё, что находится от начала и до первого символа `(`, `[` или `{`. Делаю это так `preg_match_all('/^(.+?)\(|\[|\{/iuS', $str, $result);`

Мне выводится `text1[text2](text3){`

В чём моя ошибка? Хочу чтоб на выходе было `text1` без символов, по которым делаю поиск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в Вашем регулярном выражении в том, что альтернатива идет не между символами `(`, `[` и `{`, потому что альтернатива в выражении

```
/^(.+?)\(|\[|\{/iuS
```

идет между:

1. `^(.+?)\(`
2. `\[`
3. `\{`

Таким образом срабатывает первая альтернатива и захватывает все от начала текста до первого символа `(`.

Если исправлять именно Ваше выражение, то нужно просто правильно задать альтернативу сгруппировав нужные варианты альтернативы:

```
/^(.+?)(?:\(|\[|\{)/iuS
```

`(?:...)` - группировка частей регулярного выражения без сохранения результата, так называемая "не захватывающая группа".

**P.S.**
1. `(?:\(|\[|\{)` альтернативы, состоящие из одиночных литералов красивее записать в виде символьного класса. `[([{]`, а лучше `[\(\[\{]`, чтобы не смущаться при виде одиночных "метасимволов"
2. Флаг *S* означает, что все "жадные" квантификаторы должны быть "минимальными". То есть флаг лишний, так как и так указана "минимальная" квантификация `.+?`

Answer (score 0):

Выбрать от начала строки до первой открывающей скобки:

```php
<?php
$str = 'text1[text2](text3){text4}';
preg_match_all('/^([^([{]+)/', $str, $result);
```

Comment: Работает отлично. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто разделить строку по вышеперечисленным символам:

```
$str = 'text1[text2](text3){text4}';
$result = preg_split('/[][(){}]/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```